# phonegap, sencha in android

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have an application which is almost getting finished off now. Now there is a last module which has got a listview in it. I was worndering if I could use sencha + phonegap + android in only that activity of mine. Is it possible? And also, with the tutorial in phonegap android, it was not clear as to where should I edit my androidmanyfest file. Can someone please explain that.

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

androidmanifest file is at the same folder path as src folder.

Please have a look at following image.

[image: androidmanifest]

Also see, [phonegap android wiki](https://files.pbworks.com/download/pQPPi6KHFQ/phonegap/32192877/manifest.jpg)

Comment: thanks for that. And can I use phonegap features in only one activity of mine, and rest of the activities to be used just as a normal activity in android?

Comment: in theory (and practically as well) you can.you can jump to those activities (which you call normal activity) by registering a class in launcher activity (activity extending DroidGap) and using its methods to create new intents.But why do you need sth like that? For an ideal phoneGap supported app architecture you don't need to do that.